# Using aiohttp, parse response body as a dynamic type

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, asynchronous, concurrency, aiohttp

My goal is to dynamically parse the HTTP response body from the return value of a `aiohttp.ClientSession.get` call. Is there a builtin method for achieving this? In the following example I've achieved this logic:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def get_req(url, parse_as='json', params=None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, params=params) as r:
            parse_methods = {
                'json': r.json,
                'binary': r.read,
                'text': r.text
            }
            target_method = parse_methods.get(parse_as)
            return await target_method()
asyncio.run(get_req('<some_link>', 'text')) # Will return text data from body of response.
```

My brain tells me this is not the best approach, but so far I haven't found any examples explaining how to set a dynamic parse type for `aiohttp.ClientSession`'s HTTP methods. I want to keep the `aiohttp` session  local to `get_req`.

My overall question is: How do I do achieve this logic in a more readable and efficient way?